# How to pass JSP var to runtime exec?

Tags: java, jsp, exec

Aim: I am trying to use 2 string var in a `exec` command as arguments for a shell script.

The strings are passed over fine from the HTML front, but the exec won't allow them in the exec string.

What am I missing?

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>

<html>
<head>
    <title> Test</title>
<head/>

<body>
<%
String username, password;

if(request.getParameter("txtUserName") == null)
    username = "";
else
    username = request.getParameter("txtUserName");

if(request.getParameter("txtPassword") == null)
    password = "";
else
    password = request.getParameter("txtPassword");


Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = null;
String s = null;
String cmd = "/tools/scripts/jspTest.sh";

p = r.exec(cmd + username + password);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    out.println(line);
}

p.waitFor();
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by *won't allow them*, but it's pretty clear that the way you are calling the script is not going to work.

```
cmd + username + password
```

This will result in a string like `/tools/scripts/jspTest.shmyusernamemypassword`.

If Java is trying to execute this, the system is not going to find that command (unless you have usernames/passwords embedded in script names). I think you probably need to adjust how you are passing these values (as proper arguments).

Comment: I didn't think about that. I have changed to `p=r.exec(cmd + " " + username + " " + password);` and that did the trick.